# SMTP listeners on a workstation?

Tags: linux, debian, smtp, daemon

I'm working on a Debian 7.30 (x64) workstation. I noticed I have a couple of SMTP listeners:

```
$ netstat -A inet,inet6 --listening | grep -i smtp
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:smtp          [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

I'm not sure where they are coming from. Using Debian's sysv-rc-conf, I don't see where a SMTP daemon is started:

[image]

How can I learn what started those listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making two mistakes:

- You're not using the `-p` option to `netstat`.
- You're making the bogus assumption that a process that listens on a port, and the `init.d` script that ran that process, have to be named after that port's Well Known Service name.

Use the `-p` option, and you'll find your SMTP daemon's name, which doesn't need to have the string "smtp" anywhere within it.  The associated `init.d` script doesn't even have to match the daemon program's name, moreover.

For examples:

- With qmail the programs that accept SMTP connections are usually [`tcpserver`](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html), [`s6-tcpserver`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver.html), [`tcp-socket-accept`](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh.html) or similar.
- Postfix's `init.d` script is generally named `postfix` but the actual SMTP daemon program is named [`smtpd`](http://postfix.org/smtpd.8.html).

My educated guess here is Exim, which is under "e" for both `init.d` script and SMTP daemon program name.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24317/

Comment: Thanks JdeBP, it was `exim4`. My next question is why is it running? This is a workstation and not a server. Plus, Exim has made a few appearances on Bugtraq and the NVD, so its just another vulnerable program that opens a listening socket in my eyes.

Comment: Your next question was asked two and a quarter years ago, as you can see. (-:

Comment: Thanks JdeBP. But the question was not answered. (A couple folks stated it was not a security risk, which is diametrically opposed to what I have observed about programs that open listening sockets). I'll start a new question. Thanks for the help.